# Azure Authentication .net core user consent

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

Situation
Adding additional scopes for API's in App registration not triggering user consent screen automatically.

When user has previously consented they are not redirected to the consent screen again.

I can see in various web posts references to options.Prompt = "consent" but not sure how to add this with conditional logic in the startup file.

How do I detect if there are new scopes added if the application is enhanced and they are added to the app registration and only add the options prompt redirect to the consent screen in the case of new scopes, not on every login?

.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options => {
Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);

```
options.Prompt = "select_account";

    if (**how to detect if there are new scopes**)
    {
        options.Prompt = "consent";
    }

options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context => {
    var tokenAcquisition = context.HttpContext.RequestServices
        .GetRequiredService<ITokenAcquisition>();

    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
        new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (request) => {
            var token = await tokenAcquisition
                .GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(GraphConstants.Scopes, user: context.Principal);
            request.Headers.Authorization =
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        })
    );
```

Comment: Why not use "admin consent" option on Azure portal just after the administrator added permissions?

Comment: For a consistent experience i wanted a user to be aware of what permissions the application was asking for. i find it pretty strange that there isnt a simple way of just adding an additional permission after it is live and had just assumed the login code would handle the consent experience automatically. Is this "admin consent" option on the app registration page, is it equivalent to the end user consenting?

Comment: Your users are from other tenants or the same tenant which the App registration is in?

Comment: The same tennant

Comment: If you want the users to see what permissions the application was asking for, you can delete the enterprise application associated with the app registration after you add new permissions (don't click on "admin consent"). Then the consent screen will be shown again while the users try to sign in. For the question "Is this "admin consent" option on the app registration page, is it equivalent to the end user consenting?", admin consent includes user consent. If an admin makes a consent for this tenant, users will not need to make a consent, so users will not see what permissions they need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user consent the permissions, essentially the permissions are granted to the service principal(i.e. enterprise application) corresponded to the AD App that the user logged in, navigate to the enterprise application corresponded to the AD App in the portal -> `Permissions`, you will find the permissions that the user consented.

So when the same user login the app again, it will not promote the user to consent the same permissions again by default, because the permissions have already granted to the service principal, just if there are new permissions added to the AD App -> `API permissions`, then it will promote the user to consent the new permissions again.

For your requirement, if you want the user to be aware of what permissions the application was asking for, just consent for one time is enough, I don't think you need to let him consent again and again. Also no need to detect if there are new scopes added when using `options.Prompt = "consent"`, because it will let the user consent the new permissions automatically. In conclusion, I don't think you need to do anything additional, the default behavior by azure is enough.

Comment: i did not experience it taking me to the consent screen again but perhaps it was something in my setup, i have been trying so many permutations.

Comment: @user900566 It will, unless you have clicked the `Grant admin consent for xxx` button in `API permissions` page, this means the admin consent the permissions on behalf of all the users in this tenant.